# Regular expression to match a backslash followed by a quote

Tags: java, regex

How to write a regular expression to match this `\"` (a backslash then a quote)? Assume I have a string like this:

```
<a href=\"google.com\"> click to search </a>
```

I need to replace all the `\"` with a `"`, so the result would look like:

```
<a href="google.com"> click to search </a>
```

This one does not work: `str.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"")` because it only matches the quote. Not sure how to get around with the backslash. I could have removed the backslash first, but there are other backslashes in my string.

Comment: You need more backslashes in the first parameter. It may seem a bit counter-intuitive, but if you think about, it will make sense.

Comment: To write a literal \ in the regex, use `"\\\\"` The first "double up" is to escape the slash in the string *literal* (so the resulting string *value* is \\\). Then the first slash escapes the second *in* the regexp engine so it will match a \ character. Fun, eh?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to decode a string that may contain escape sequences, where backslash is the escape character. What should the output of your decoder be when the input contains backslash-backslash-quote? Make sure you write a test for that case.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you ***don't need any of regex mechanisms like predefined character classes \d, quantifiers etc.*** instead of `replaceAll` which expects regex use `replace` which expects literals

```
str = str.replace("\\\"","\"");
```

Both methods will replace *all* occurrences of targets, but `replace` will treat targets literally.

---

BUT if you really ***must*** use regex you are looking for

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"")
```

`\` is special character in regex (used for instance to create `\d` - character class representing digits). To make regex treat `\` as normal character you need to place another `\` before it to turn off its special meaning (you need to escape it). So regex which we are trying to create is `\\`.

But to create string literal representing text `\\` so you could pass it to regex engine you need to write it as four `\` (`"\\\\"`), because `\` is also special character in String literals (part of code written using `"..."`) since it can be used for instance as `\t` to represent tabulator.
That is why you also need to escape `\` there.

In short you need to escape `\` twice:

- in regex `\\`
- and then in String literal `"\\\\"`

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a regular expression.

```
str.replace("\\\"", "\"")
```

should work just fine.

The `replace` method takes two substrings and replaces all non-overlapping occurrences of the first with the second.  Per the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

> ```
> public String replace(CharSequence target,
>                       CharSequence replacement)
> ```
>
> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for example, replacing `"aa"` with `"b"` in the string `"aaa"` will result in `"ba"` rather than `"ab"`.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `str.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\\\"")` 
because Java will replace `\`  twice:

(1) `\\\\\"` --> `\\"` (for string) 
(2) `\\"` --> `\"` (for regex)