# Spring MVC url matching with regex

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc, regex-negation

I'm trying to use the regex possibilities of Spring MVC's RequestMapping to distinguish between several REST APIs:

```
/somepath/{item:[^&?/]+}/{subitem:[^&?/]+}
/somepath/{item:[^&?/]+}
/somepath
```

In each case the API returns a totally different JSON object.

Spring MVC has the *usually* useful habit of conflating multiple slashes or ignoring trailing slashes. However, I need to get around that in this case. So I'm using regular expressions to handle the cases with the path variables are empty i.e. to stop `/somepath//asubitem` being matched to the second API rather than the first.

The problem is that when I use a slash character in the regex, the pattern will not match. Just using `[^&?]+` matches but obviously this is not quite what I need.

Does anyone have an idea why we have this regex behaviour and how to get around it?

Comment: you have to escape the `/` by using another `/` so `//` would match your `/` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769555/java-regular-expression-to-match-a-backslash-followed-by-a-quote) you will find more information from the SO-Community in the accepted answer below

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help. The cited post talks about doubling back slashes rather than forward slashes.

Comment: the `+` quantifier is enforcing at least one character between the double slashes: use `*`

Comment: Take your point but it doesn't help. It seems the the double slashes are conflated _before_ lookup:
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping -- Looking up handler method for path /somepath/asubitem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
/\//ig; //  Matches /
```

Refer following url for more detail

[Forward Slash with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657152/matching-a-forward-slash-with-a-regex)

Comment: Errr, this _is_ a java question. Not a javascript question. Java doesn't use a slashy syntax for regexes.