# Regex pattern for a substring in the matching pattern

Tags: regex

I have a string log file which has a pattern and I need help to get the right regex to replace a pattern in java

The pattern in the file is

```
{\"KJ01\":{\"systemId\":\"ER\",\"authenticationChar\":\"adf72a0db2cbd364-62d3aa2.03eda_902f\",\"serialNo\":\"KJ01202004241755021736\"
```

I want to replace

```
authenticationChar\":\"adf72a0db2cbd364-62d3aa2.03eda_902f\"
```

with 
`authenticationChar\":\"xxx"`

So basically I am trying to mask the authenticationChar in the logs.

The special chars it may contain are -._\

I've been trying various regex but I keep getting PatternSyntaxException.

One of my attempts was:

```
content = content.replaceAll("(authenticationChar\\\":\\\")([ ]*[0-9A-Za-z-._\\]*[ ]*)*", "(authenticationChar\\\":\\\"xxx");
```

but that did not work
Can anyone kindly help me here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```java
content = content.replaceAll("(?<=authenticationChar\\\\\":\\\\\")[^\\\\]+", "xxx");
```

- `(?<=...)` - that is a positive lookbehind, it is non-capturing, so it will not be replaced
- `[^\\\\]+` - this one is "everything before the next backslash", the thing you actually need to replace

Comment: Thanks @kishkin but I get a ```java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 32
(?<=authenticationChar\":\")[^\]+``` error with the ^ pointing to the + sign.

Comment: updated, but not sure :)

Comment: now, pretty sure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11769570/279806

Comment: another fix. ‍♂️ please let me know if this works

Comment: Sure. Ill try it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks @Kishkin